# Erro Unavailable Database ao tentar conectar ClientDataSet usando base local Firebird

Tags: firebird-2.5, delphi-2010

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação em `Delphi 2010` e estou usando `Firebird 2.5.`
Eu criei um **DataModule** e coloquei um **SQLConnection, SQLDataSet, ClientDataSet** e ao clicar com o botão direito sobre o **ClientDataSet** na opção **Assign Local Data...** está dando o erro **Unavailable Database** conforme print em anexo.

> **Name**       SQLConnection
>   **Driver**      Firebird
>   **Database** C:\ProjetosDelphi\CentralRit\db\BDLIVRO.FDB
>   **UserName**    SYSDBA
>   **PassWord**    masterkey
>   **GetDriverFunc**   getSQLDriverINTERBASE
>   **libraryName** dbxfb.dll
>   **Vendorlib**   fbclient.dll
>
> **Name**       SQLDataSet
>   **SchemaName**  C:\ProjetosDelphi\CentralRit\db\BDLIVRO.FDB
>   **SQLConnect**  SQLConnection
>   **ConnectionName**  FBConnection
>   **Driver**      FireBird
>   **DataBase**    C:\ProjetosDelphi\CentralRit\db\BDLIVRO.FDB
>   **UserName**    SYSDBA
>   **PassWord**    masterkey
>   **GetDriverFunc**   getSQLDriverINTERBASE
>   **libraryName** dbxfb.dll
>   **Vendorlib**   fbclient.dll
>
> **Name**       ClientDataSet
>   **FileName**    C:\ProjetosDelphi\CentralRit\db\BDLIVRO.FDB

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você verificou se os serviços do Firebird estão executando normalmente? Consegue acessar qualquer outro banco de dados através de outra aplicação?

Comment: ola para mim funcionou desta forma com localhost:C:\caminho do banco